Accessing WordPress Contact Form 7 Radio Buttons by number, not description
I've set up a Contact 7 form that uses some conditional logic at https://eastsurreymuseum.com/contact-2/
If you click on radio button 4, you get an additional text box.
My code, is however, rather clumsy
show [CF-Reason] if [R-Reason] equals "I am interested in volunteering at the museum"
I'd rather compare the NUMBER of the radio button (i.e. 4 in this case) than its description, is this possible?
Thank you!
I initially tried
show [CF-Reason] if [R-Reason] equals 4
before the penny dropped that CF-Reason contained the reason text, not the radio button number
